# Combinación de listas en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

me gustaría saber como hacer para que una función reciba n cantidad de listas y regrese todas las posibles combinaciones de la siquiente manera:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]

b=[5,6,7]

c=[8,9]

d=[1,4,7]

Listafinal=[a,b,c,d]
```

Que solo 1 numero de cada lista se ubique en una posicion fija de la listafinal y que arroje resultados:

```
[1,5,8,1]

[1,5,8,4]

[1,5,8,7]

[1,5,9,1]

[1,5,9,4]

[1,5,9,7]

[1,6,8,1]
```

y así hasta que recorra todas las combinaciones

Pd: Lo necesito para una cantidad N de listas, no un número fijo de listas.

Comment: Y que pruebas has hecho? Que has pensado? La finalidad del foro es ayudar en todo lo posible pero no hacer programas desde 0. ¡¡Si tienes código hecho muéstralo y entre todos nos ayudamos!! Y si no, di que has pensado, cual es tu problema específico... ¡¡Ánimo y bienvenido!! :)

Comment: No quize publicar el codigo entero porque era muy largo. encontré una manera de hacerlo pero me parecio muy extensa y quería saber si había una manera más óptima y ya la encontré

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que la función `itertools.product()` (que forma parte de la biblioteca estándar python) hace precisamente lo que necesitas.

```
import itertools
for combinacion in itertools.product(a,b,c,d):
    print(combinacion)
```

Y resulta en:

```
(1, 5, 8, 1)
(1, 5, 8, 4)
(1, 5, 8, 7)
(1, 5, 9, 1)
(1, 5, 9, 4)
(1, 5, 9, 7)
(1, 6, 8, 1)
(1, 6, 8, 4)
(1, 6, 8, 7)
(1, 6, 9, 1)
(1, 6, 9, 4)
....
(4, 7, 8, 7)
(4, 7, 9, 1)
(4, 7, 9, 4)
(4, 7, 9, 7)
```

Para el caso más general de un número variable de listas, si tienes todas las listas en otra, por ejemplo `todas=[a,b,c,d]`, puedes usar el operador de *unpacking* (`*`) para convertir esa lista en una serie de parámetros, así:

```
for combinacion in itertools.product(*todas):
    print(combinacion)
```

Comment: Ok eso era justo lo que estaba buscando, no sabía que se podia hacer eso, de verdad que muchas gracias!